# keydown event delete my div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my JavaScript file I created 2 events; 
Key-down and click;

When you click on the button or press Enter, the text written in input field is show up in a `div` text area; This code works for the button click event but doesn't work correctly in key-down event.

HTML code:

```
<div id="chatarea">
  <div id="jqarea">
    <div class="chatboxcontent"></div>                      
  </div>
</div>
<div class="chatbox">                   
  <input type="hidden" name="cfrom" id="cfrom" value="<?php echo $cuser; ?>" ></input>
  <p><input type="text" name="digit" id="digit" size="50"/></p>             
  <p><button class="btn" title="send" type="button">                    
     <span>Send</span>
      </button>
  </p>                                      
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
$("#digit").keydown(function(event){
        if (event.which == 13) {                
            filltxtarea($("#digit").val());         
        }
});

$(".btn").click(function(){     
    filltxtarea($("#digit").val());             
}); 

function filltxtarea(desctext) {    
    var uchat = $("#cfrom").val();      
    //$(".chatboxcontent").append('<div class=chatboxmessage><span class="chatboxmessagefrom">' + uchat + ': </span><span class="chatboxmessagecontent">' + desctext + '</span></div>');        
    $('#digit').val('');
    $('#digit').focus();        
    $.post('chat.php','action=newrow&message='+desctext,function(data){
        if (data==='failed'){alert("error in mysqli")};
    });     
}
});
function chatHeartbeat(){               
$.ajax({        
url: 'chat.php?action=chatheartbeat',    
dataType: 'json', 
cache: false,
success: function(data) {                       
    alert("0");
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){            
        if(item){       
            alert("1");
            $(".chatboxcontent").append('<div class=chatboxmessage><span class="chatboxmessagefrom">'+item.f+': </span><span class="chatboxmessagecontent">'+item.m+'</span></div>');
        }
    });                 
}   
});
setTimeout('chatHeartbeat();',1000);
}
```

When I use `click` anything work and I can see alert(1) and alert(2) but with key-down it create a new row in the db but I have only alert(0).... How can this be possible??? Any idea????

Comment: `<input>` is self closing => `<input type="hidden" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try prevent default, sometimes with enter key you  can have unwanted behavior:

```
$("#digit").keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        filltxtarea($("#digit").val());
    }
});
```